# PHP: trying to create a new line with <br

Tags: php, html, line-breaks

I am trying to create a new line between product $id and $name but however I am getting an error, please could you help me.

```
echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=".$id."'>".<br />$name. "</a> ";
    }

    echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=".$id."'>".<br />$name. "</a> ";
    }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 41

Comment: The syntax highlighting here should give you a clue.... you need the `< br />` ___inside___ your quotes (`"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=".$id."'><br />".$name. "</a> ";
    }

    echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=".$id."'><br />".$name. "</a> ";
    }
```

Comment: np - you can show your appreciation with an upvote & accept of the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Your concat is wrong.you need to use like below

```
echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=".$id."'><br />".$name."</a> ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You Missed Quotations In

tags Always Written in Double Quotations In Php.

```
echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=".$id."'><br />".$name."</a> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed up with the quotations

change it to this

```
echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=$id'><br />$name</a> ";
    }

    echo "<a href='searchdetails2.php?vid=$id'><br />$name</a> ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concating a html element as a php constant. Any html should be surrounded with quotes lie this.
`echo '<a href="searchdetails2.php?vid='.$id."'><br />'.$name.'</a>';`